# Axis positions other than the edges?

Tags: python, bokeh

Graphs in Bokeh have the axes along the edges. I can control
which edge by adding

```
x_axis_location="above"|"below",
y_axis_location="left"|"right"
```

to my call to bokeh.plotting.figure(). But what if I want the x axis to be along the line y=0, and the y axis to be at x=0? That seems like it should be the default (because that's how mathematicians always do it), but I can't see any way in which it is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to set an fixed position to your axes. In your case you want to set `fixed_location = 0` for both, the x.axis (which is below) and the y-axis (which is left).

**Minimal Example**

```
from bokeh.plotting import show, figure, output_notebook
output_notebook()
p = figure(width=300,
           height=300,
           x_range=(-11,11),
           y_range=(-11,11),
          )
p.below[0].fixed_location = 0
p.left[0].fixed_location = 0
show(p)
```

**Output**

[image: Axis with fixed position]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I ran into the problem that if the date range does not include 0 in a particular direction, that axis might not be visible. I solved it by also adding this line
```
plot.dot(x=[ 0 ], y=[ 0 ], color="black")
```
which is less elegant than querying and setting the range directly, but is clear and gets the job done. Thanks!